# Sorting the List by Stream API in two orders

Tags: java, list, sorting, java-stream

I have an array of class `Person`. Let's call it `arr_Person`. Each instance of the `Person` class has an `int` priority type parameter that can take the values 0,1,2,3,4.

I need to get a sorted list of objects through the Stream API when:

- first all instances of `Person` with priority=0;
- then there are all instances with priority=4, then 3, then  2, then  1;

That is, first 0, then in reverse order. How to do it? That is, what should I write in sorted: `Arrays.stream(arr_Person).sorted(???)`

Comment: create your own comparator that defines how each priority should be ordered

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `.sorted(Comparator.comparing((Person p) -> p.getPriority() == 0) .thenComparing(Person::getPriority).reversed())`

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple comparator that does what you want.
edit: I went back and rewrote another comparator because I was bored. Now it allows you to define which numbers are priority numbers which should be in front (and in natural order) and which numbers should come after priority numbers and sorted in reverse order.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    List<Integer> ints = List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3, 4, 0, 1, 0);
    List<Integer> ints2 = new ArrayList<>(List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3, 4, 0, 1, 0));
    Comparator<Integer> intComparator = (t0, t1) -> {
        if (t0 == 0) {
            if (t1 == 0) {
                return 0; //both equal doesnt really matter if swap or not
            } else {
                return -1; //first item is 0, do not swap positions
            }
        } else if (t1 == 0) {
            return 1; //second item is 0, swap positions
        } else {
            return t1.compareTo(t0); //reverse order
        }
    };
    System.out.println(ints.stream().sorted(intComparator).toList());
    System.out.println(ints2.stream().sorted(new PriorityNumbersFrontAndReverseSortTheRest(List.of(0), List.of(1, 2, 3, 4))).toList());
}

static class PriorityNumbersFrontAndReverseSortTheRest implements Comparator<Integer> {
    private final Set<Integer> priorityNumbers = new HashSet<>();
    private final Set<Integer> regularNumbers = new HashSet<>();

    public PriorityNumbersFrontAndReverseSortTheRest() {
        this.setPriorityNumbers(List.of(0, 1));
        this.setRegularNumbers(List.of(2, 3, 4));
        checkNoDuplicates();
    }

    public PriorityNumbersFrontAndReverseSortTheRest(List<Integer> priority, List<Integer> regular) {
        this.setPriorityNumbers(priority);
        this.setRegularNumbers(regular);
        checkNoDuplicates();
    }

    private void checkNoDuplicates() {
        if (!Collections.disjoint(priorityNumbers, regularNumbers)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("There exists duplicates in the priority numbers and regular numbers");
        }
    }

    public void resetNumbers(List<Integer> priority, List<Integer> regular) {
        this.setPriorityNumbers(priority);
        this.setRegularNumbers(regular);
        checkNoDuplicates();
    }

    private void setPriorityNumbers(List<Integer> ints) {
        this.priorityNumbers.clear();
        this.priorityNumbers.addAll(ints);
    }

    private void setRegularNumbers(List<Integer> ints) {
        this.regularNumbers.clear();
        this.regularNumbers.addAll(ints);
        checkNoDuplicates();
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Integer t0, Integer t1) {
        if (priorityNumbers.contains(t0)) {
            if (priorityNumbers.contains(t1)) {
                return t0.compareTo(t1);
            } else {
                return -1;
            }
        } else if (priorityNumbers.contains(t1)) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return t1.compareTo(t0);
        }
    }
}
```

The comments in the code describe why it works. It gives an output of:

```
[0, 0, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: A comparator has a specific contract. You should not make assumption about the caller performing “swap positions” operations. Such assumptions eventually lead to the [“comparator violates contract” exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=comparator+violates+contract) or inconsistent results. Further, using negation to reverse a comparator is broken. Just think about what happens if the result of `t0.compareTo(t1)` happens to be `Integer.MIN_VALUE`. It’s not clear why you even come up with this at the end, as the previously shown reversal `t1.compareTo(t0)` is simpler and more efficient.

Comment: @Holger Thanks for the info! I didnt know about this comparator violates contract before as well as the negation to reverse a comparator. The thing at the end was copy pasted and I forgot to change it when i came back to the code later on

Comment: I would delete my answer, but i ll just leave it here to preserve your comment.